# Strange Issue with Visual Studio 2022 and c# Value gets added every time I type(

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Strange Issue in Visual studio 2022 when I type the first parenthesis. say for example I have this Foo(foo) visual studio wants to throw in word value, but it's greyed out, so foo now looks like this

foo (value foo) No matter what I do I can't get rid of the word unless I delete the first parenthesis what can I do to solve this?
Sorry if this is not the right place to ask such a question.

Looked online looked at my extensions looked though VS options found nothing about my problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE7Ts.png)

Comment: Can you share screenshot?

Comment: Are you talking about the "value:" label? It's called an "Inline Hint".

Comment: screen added. How do we disable? I've looked up and down VS and nothing helps. No I do not have GitHub copilot

Comment: @  madrelection Yes i am. so disable inline hints will fix this?

Comment: Yeah, that's Inline Hints.  It's under C# > Advanced.

Comment: Why do you want to disable it?- IMHO it is very useful. Note that this is just a display feature, it is not part of the code, the C# code contains just what you type.

Comment: This is just a hint that comes with the software and will not affect your daily programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uncheck Display inline parameter name hints to hide this hint.
[image]